# PhpMyAdmin fail to export any Database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

It will just give me the below error on localhost/phpmyadmin/export.php

Fatal error: Call to a member function getHeader() on a non-object in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php on line 1067

I've already replaced installation and no luck so far. Can anyone help me?

Comment: From the source.. `if (isset($_SESSION['profiling'])) {
        $header   = $response->getHeader();` Just disable profiling (unset the checkbox).

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version is it?

Comment: it's version  4.2.7.1

@Cheery , How can I disable profiling, sorry but Im very new to php and Mysql in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have **Profiling** turned-off in phpmyadmin.

To check that, you can run any query inside phpmyadmin and look for **Profiling** checkbox, make sure it's unchecked.
[image: phpmyadmin image with Profiling option]

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by simply rebooting system. There was some problem with commoninc.php